# Angular2 bind using conditional operator

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a question about the binding in angular2.

I wrote a simple component, this is the code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'drawer-item',
    templateUrl: '../res/views/drawer-item.html'
})
export class DrawerItemComponent
{
    @Input() text:string;
    @Input() icon:string;
    @Input() textClass:string;
}

<div class="drawer-item-text word-wrap {{textClass}}"> {{text}}</div>
<i class="mdi mdi-{{icon}} drawer-item-img"></i>
```

I use it like this:

```
<drawer-item (click)="selectCompany()" [text]="selectedCompanyLabel" [icon]="selectedCompanyIcon" [textClass]="selectedCompanyClass"></drawer-item>
```

As you can see I'm binding the text with variable, for example with *selectedCompanyLabel*.
In this way everything works great, and if *selectedCompanyLabel* change tha label changes as well.

I would avoid that variable using something like:

```
[text]="company ? 'company.name' : 'Select a company'"
```

But is this way the content is not binded. So if *company* changes, the label is not updated.

But if I use that strategy in a style, it works! For example something like works great:

```
<div class="company ? 'italic' : 'bold'"> ... </div>
```

Do you know why?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would use the following instead:

```
[text]="company ? company.name : 'Select a company'"
```

No quotes for `company.name`.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure from your question what the problem is but I guess this is what you're looking for

```
[text]="company?.name"
```